# Add a product to cart in checkout cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cart, addtocart

Would it be possible to add a button in checkout cart page to add a product to cart?

That product would always have the same SKU and would be dynamically created. By dynamically I mean that the price would depend on the product it is being added to (I guess I could just pass the SKU of the product it is being addded to in a URL of a button or form).

Any ideas or suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would work by loading a product by `$sku` & generate the appropriate add-to-cart HTML:

```
<?php
    $sku = 'your_sku';
    $url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku)); 
?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $url; ?>')">
  <span>
    <span>
      <?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>
    </span>
  </span>
</button>
```

You'd need to place the code in `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`